# How to install multiple packages?

Tags: r, package

How would I got about installing multiple packages in R?

I tried the following code:

```
install.packages("EIAdata", "gdata", "ggmap", "ggplot2","gridExtra","ISOweek","kobe","lubridate","maps","MASS","memisc","pander","plyr","psych","Quandl","quantmod","reshape2","rgeos","Rgnuplot","RODBC","scales","sp","sqldf","stockPortfolio","stringi","stringr","XLConnect", "xlsReadWrite","zipcode")
```

This code works:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

Why won't the line with the multiple packages work?

Answer (score 136):

Elementary:  form a vector via `c(...)`:

```
 install.packages(c("EIAdata", "gdata", "ggmap", "ggplot2")) # rest omitted
```

so that you have *one* first argument of length > 1.

Personally, I prefer `install.r` from [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) so I'd do (at the Unix command-line):

```
  install.r EIAdata gdata ggmap ggplot2    # rest omitted again
```

Note that there is no limit to the number of arguments. It was just easier for me to write this with four packages than the 20-some from your example.

Comment: Worked like a charm...takes maybe milsec for littler to install and everything else is smooth !

Comment: :-)  And better still, with the current version on `options("Ncpus"=4)` (or another value) it uses the number of chosen cpus (or, rather, cores) to install in parallel.

Comment: Ooo thats gr8 ! Thanks Dirk ! I wonder by any means littler "checks" and "skips" unchanged package versions for faster builds ?!

Comment: If you _list them explicitly_ it will install them.  If you don't want a package, don't list it.  Dependencies are automagically pulled in.  Also, `install2.r` is more featureful; we could add a 'skip if present in same version' but I don't consider this to be urgent.

Comment: Alright. I am trying to automate the installation with "requirements.txt". Is there any way that install.r directly takes a file name (maybe an option like -f ...i dindnt see in examples !) and does the magic ?!

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to specify package version, such as `install.packages('plotly', version='4.5.6')`

Comment: There is no `version='...'` argument to `install.packages()`.  Because there is a `...` it is accepted. passed on and --- simply ignored. As an illustration I just asked for `install.packages("digest", version="0.6.32")` for the one-but-last version but of course and as expected the current version 0.6.33 was installed.

Answer (score 13):

```
# Here we have a list of packages we want to install

load.lib<-c("EIAdata", "gdata", "ggmap","ggplot2","gridExtra","ISOweek",
"Kobe","lubridate","maps","MASS","memisc","pander","plyr","psych",
"Quandl","quantmod","reshape2","rgeos","Rgnuplot","RODBC","scales",
"sp","sqldf","stockPortfolio","stringi","stringr","XLConnect", 
"xlsReadWrite","zipcode")

# Then we select only the packages that aren't currently installed.

install.lib <- load.lib[!load.lib %in% installed.packages()

# And finally we install the missing packages, including their dependency.
for(lib in install.lib) install.packages(lib,dependencies=TRUE)
# After the installation process completes, we load all packages.
sapply(load.lib,require,character=TRUE)
```

Comment: This answer needs some explanation of what is going on.

Comment: This was a neat solution. I cleaned the code and added some explanations, and my edit is pending approval.

Comment: add "]" (closing bracket) at the end of the string "install.lib <- load.lib[!load.lib %in% installed.packages()"

Answer (score 7):

Here is a *sweet  suite* of data science packages

You will also need to pay attention to make sure you're not using different styled quotation marks that are sometimes created in text editors if you’re using a foreign language.

`$ R`

`> install.packages(c("remotes","readxl","googlesheets","haven", "readr", "rio", "Hmisc", "sqldf", "jsonlite", "XML", "httr", "quantmod", "tidyquant", "rvest", "dplyr", "purrr", "reshape2", "tidyr", "magrittr", "validate", "testthat", "data.table", "stringr", "lubridate", "zoo", "editR", "knitr", "officer", "listviewer", "DT", "ggplot2", "ggiraph", "dygraphs", "googleVis", "metricsgraphics", "RColorBrewer", "sf", "leaflet", "ggmap", "tmap", "tmaptools", "mapsapi", "tidycensus", "glue", "rga", "RSiteCatalyst", "roxygen2", "shiny", "flexdashboard", "openxlsx", "gmodels", "janitor", "car", "rcdimple", "foreach", "scales", "plotly", "highcharter", "profvis", "tidytext", "diffobj", "Prophet", "feather", "fst", "googleAuthR", "cloudyR"))`

If you're installing from CLI R will say `--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---` and after a couple of seconds a GUI will pop up and show a list of global download mirrors.

If you're using the latest version of R you might get a warning that certain older packages aren't available for your R version which you can choose to ignore, find newer packages or use an older version of R.

> Warning message:
>   packages ‘editR’, ‘rga’, ‘rcdimple’, ‘Prophet’, ‘cloudyR’ are not available (for R version 3.4.2)

The compressed .tgz files will be downloaded somewhere like `/private/var/folders/2k/p756_j5x0x5fqplwrq74j1sh0000gn/T/RtmpMTzQQ5/downloaded_packages`

Actual packages located in `/Users/tymac/Library/R/3.4/library` and `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library`.

You can view packages a couple of other ways.

- Open R app/console
- --> Help --> Html help
- Reference --> Packages

or

- Open RStudio
- --> Help --> R Help
- help area
- --> Reference --> Packages

Comment: officeR can not be installed because it does not exist, it should be `officer`

Comment: This answer starts off with a long list of packages that has nothing to do with the OP's question. It also does not seem to answer the question at all. Third strike is blaming the appearance of non-standard quotation marks on "foreign" languages, it has little to do with that language used. Besides that, for most users on this site, it is English that is foreign.