# Remote install of multiple R packages (with, without depends) from Ubuntu CLI

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I have to perform a remote R installation on an Ubuntu 16.10 system. As part of this, I have to install specific packages on that host. I want to install these packages `Rcmdr`,`list`,`ggplot2`,`afex`,`lsmeans`. Since I am doing this remotely, I cannot use

```
sudo -i R
```

to first enter the R CLI and then install with `install.packages()`. Instead I must somehow install the packages from the Ubuntu CLI.

I found these links:

1. [multiple R package installation with
   install.packages()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041423/how-to-install-multiple-packages-in-r)
2. [R CMD INSTALL -l usage syntax to install multiple packages in
   section
   6.3](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-admin.html)
3. [Use of repos parameter inside
   install.packages()](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-r-on-ubuntu-14-04)

However, some packages have dependencies:

- The `list` package depends on `utils` and `sandwich`.
- The `Rcmdr` package depends on `grDevices`, `utils`, `splines`, `RcmdrMisc`, `car`.
- The `ggplot2` package also has dependencies.

I would like to install only the packages `Rcmdr`,`list`,`ggplot2` with all their dependencies. Normally, I would do it this way:

```
install.packages(c('Rcmdr','list','ggplot2'), dependencies=TRUE)
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. How do I specify the dependencies option in `R CMD` for one package
   only? Is this the way to install them

   ```
   R CMD INSTALL -l Rcmdr dependencies=TRUE, list dependencies=TRUE, \
   ggplot2 dependencies=TRUE, afex, lsmeans
   ```

   or this incorrect?
2. Also, how to I specify the `repos` parameter inside `R CMD INSTALL -l`?

**EDIT**

As per the first comment below, `sudo` is not needed above.i.e. `sudo -i R` can be replaced by `R`.

Comment: You can't start R on the CLI at all just because it's remote? I'm not sure why you don't have `sudo` over a VNC connection, but I wasn't aware that `sudo` would even be necessary just to launch R CLI and install packages. Can you verify that?

Comment: I would need to start, install and close the R CLI. I'm not sure how to do this. Also, in my scenario, doesn't it seem more intuitive to install from the Ubuntu CLI?

Comment: Well you'd just type `R` then do everything as you normally do. Regarding which one is more intuitive, I guess that's subjective but I can't help you with the `R CMD INSTALL` way because I've never hard to do it that way. *Having said that* in Linux I do often find it more efficient to install packages using `apt` or `yum`. The dependencies are usually non-issue that way and it's often faster. `apt-get install r-cran-ggplot2`, etc. Though I suppose you may need sudo for that too. Is it some company policy or what's preventing you from using `sudo`?

Comment: When I use `install.packages()`, a dialog box opens up asking to select a mirror. In my scenario (remote install), I need to automate this. With your approach, would you specify the repos using `install.packages(c('Rcmdr','list','ggplot2'), dependencies=TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')`? Or is there some other site I need to reference for `repos`?

Comment: I just left my computer so I cannot verify this but I think that that pop up only happens once and also setting the repo that way should work. I can verify this when I get back to my computer later

Comment: Okay, no problem. Thanks for your help regarding this. Looks like there are a couple of options: a post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488174/how-to-select-a-cran-mirror-in-r) mentions using `repos='http://cran.r-project.org'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding your questions:

#### Question 1

This may not be the best approach. Consider instead `Rscript -e 'install.packages(...)'` which is what `R CMD INSTALL ...` calls anyway. You have better control over options here.  And read on...

#### Question 2

On all Ubuntu machines at work and home I do this via `/etc/R/Rprofile.site` via something like

```
## Example of Rprofile.site
local({
    r <- getOption("repos")
    r["CRAN"] <- "https://cloud.r-project.org"
    r["ghrr"] <- "https://ghrr.github.io/drat"
    options(repos = r)
})
```

where we usually add a third and network-local repo.  You may just want CRAN here -- it uses the 'always-close to you' CDN administered by RStudio for the R Project and R Consortium.  The ghrr drat is a helper repo I set up.

#### Question 3

`sudo` is not needed per something I add to the official Debian/Ubuntu package for R -- but you need to be a member of the group that owns `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`.

Now, if I may, two more suggestions:

#### Littler

The `r` executable is available to you via `sudo apt-get install r-cran-littler`.  I use it on the command-line; and you probably want to look into the basic `install.r` script and the extended `install2.r`.  I tend to create a softlink from `/usr/local/bin` to the package directory for these and other (such as `update.r`).  I have been running many (Ubuntu and Debian) machines like that for many years.

#### Michael Rutter repos, and Docker

We actually have about 3000 CRAN packages as *binaries* for Ubuntu so you could just do `sudo apt-get install ...` and *all* dependendies would get resolved.  Look eg in [this script of mine](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/r-travis/blob/master/run.sh) (which uses them on Travis) or some of the Docker files I maintain such as [this one](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/master/r-apt/yakkety/Dockerfile).

Comment: Thanks. Great answer!

Comment: My pleasure.  There is also a (very low volume) list dedicated to tricks and questions around this: [r-sig-debian](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-debian). You may want to subscribe and lurk.